# JavaFX ObservableList with extractor changes behaviour depending on the existence of a listener

Tags: java, javafx

The following problem has been the source of a bug in my JavaFX application. The weird thing is that the behaviour depends on whether a specific JavaFX property has a listener attached to it or not. Everything works when the property is observed by a `ChangeListener`, otherwise not. It's starting to drive me crazy...

I managed to break it down to a minimal code example. First we need a class that exposes a property that changes every now and then. Here it's called `nameProperty()`. In this example I chose to spawn a separate thread that continuously modifies the property, but in the real application it happens by user interaction.

```
class TestClass {
    private final SimpleObjectProperty<String> name = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public TestClass() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    Platform.runLater(() -> name.set("A"));
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    Platform.runLater(() -> name.set("B"));
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<String> nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

In the main method, on the FX application thread, an `ObservableList<TestClass>` is created with an extractor so that changes to the `nameProperty()` of list elements are reported by the `ListChangeListener`. We then create an instance of the test class, add it to the list and add a `ListChangeListener` to observe updates to the list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Platform.startup(() -> {
        Callback<TestClass, Observable[]> extractor = obj -> new Observable[]{ obj.nameProperty() };
        ObservableList<TestClass> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(extractor);

        TestClass test = new TestClass();
        list.add(test);

        list.addListener((ListChangeListener<TestClass>) c -> {
            while(c.next()) {
                if(c.wasUpdated()) {
                    System.out.println("List element was updated");
                }
            }
        });
    });

    Thread.sleep(60*60*1000);
}
```

My expectation for the output was that it would look like this, due to the list extractor and the property being continuously modified:

```
List element was updated
List element was updated
List element was updated
List element was updated
List element was updated
...
```

But instead it looks like this:

```
List element was updated
*silence*
```

Now the weird part is that as soon as a `ChangeListener` is added to the `nameProperty()` anywhere in the code, for example

```
test.nameProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {}));
```

it seems to work just as expected and the list produces change notifications continuously.

Just observing a property should not change the behaviour of other things bound to that property, right? But if this were a bug in JavaFX, it would be a really obvious and fundamental one in my opinition. So maybe I did mess something up, even though the program seems very simple. I'm using OpenJFX version 21 on Windows 10, by the way.

Comment: Your example code is slightly broken, because you should only register list change listeners on the FX Application Thread. This doesn't change the behavior, however. I believe what is happening here (though I'm not quite sure) is that the extractor works by registering a `WeakChangeListener` with the specified property, and that listener is getting garbage collected.

Comment: @James_D As far as I know, anything from the `javafx.base` module can be used on any thread, and is intentionally designed to allow use outside the context of a JavaFX application. Though nothing there is safe to be used by unsynchronized concurrent threads. Of course, once an observable is connected to the UI, then it should only be interacted with on the FX thread specifically.

Comment: @Slaw *"anything from the `javafx.base` module can be used on any thread"*. This is certainly true. But I *think* (I may be wrong) that a listener needs to be registered on the same thread as the one on which changes are made.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I have changed the example so that the listeners are registered on the FX application thread too. The behaviour of the code is the same as before though.

Comment: @James_D I think the more important thing is that a _happens-before_ relationship is established.

Comment: I am not sure what's going on but it appears that adding `c.getList().get(0).nameProperty().toString());` causes things to act as expected.  `System.out.println("List element was updated" + c.getList().get(0).nameProperty().toString());`

Comment: `observableList.addListener((ListChangeListener<TestClass>) c -> {
                while(c.next()) {
                    if(c.wasUpdated()) {
                        System.out.println("List element was updated" + c.getList().get(0).nameProperty());
                    }
                }
            });`

Comment: @SedJ601 Calling `toString()` has the side-effect of validating the property (because the implementation calls `get()`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note the extractor returns an array of `Observable`, and if we look at the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.base/javafx/beans/Observable.html):

> Implementations of this class should strive to generate as few events as possible to avoid wasting too much time in event handlers. Implementations in this library mark themselves as invalid when the first invalidation event occurs. They do not generate anymore invalidation events until their value is recomputed and valid again.

The `name` property starts off in a valid state. You set the property, it's invalidated, fires an invalidation event, and ultimately the list change listener is notified of an update. But then you never query the `name` property, meaning it is never validated. Thus, it remains in an invalid state and does not fire any more invalidation events despite it being set (to different values) over and over. You need to validate the observable(s) if you want to keep being notified of invalidation events.

Here's an example showing the difference between validating the observable and not:

```java
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doTestWithoutValidation();
        doTestWithValidation();
    }

    static void doTestWithoutValidation() {
        StringProperty element = new SimpleStringProperty();

        ObservableList<Observable> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(e -> new Observable[]{e});
        list.add(element);

        list.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Observable> change) -> {
            while (change.next()) {
                if (change.wasUpdated()) {
                    System.out.println("List element updated");
                }
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Doing test WITHOUT validations...");

        element.set("Foo");
        element.set("Bar");
        element.set("Baz");

        System.out.println("DONE!");
        System.out.println();
    }

    static void doTestWithValidation() {
        StringProperty element = new SimpleStringProperty();

        ObservableList<Observable> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(e -> new Observable[]{e});
        list.add(element);

        list.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Observable> change) -> {
            while (change.next()) {
                if (change.wasUpdated()) {
                    System.out.println("List element updated");
                }
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Doing test WITH validations...");

        element.set("Foo");
        element.get(); // validate
        element.set("Bar");
        element.get(); // validate
        element.set("Baz");

        System.out.println("DONE!");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Doing test WITHOUT validations...
List element updated
DONE!

Doing test WITH validations...  
List element updated
List element updated
List element updated
DONE!
```

You also have to be careful of garbage collection. In your code, after updating it to solve the concurrency problems that were present, I believe it's possible the `ObservableList` itself becomes eligible for garbage collection after the `Runnable` (passed to `startup`) returns.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. Didn't know that JavaFX properties are that clever. But it seems like you are right. Even just changing the action in the list's change listener to `System.out.println("List element was updated to " + test.nameProperty().get());` solves the problem. Now the remaining question for me is why the property wasn't used/validated in my original code, but that's another topic.

Comment: @Stefan If you find this is not the problem in your real code, I suggest checking to see if anything is being garbage collected prematurely (i.e., if you're not keeping a strong reference to objects you need).